# Issues with geom_smooth and gganimate when creating an animtion

Tags: r, ggplot2, animated-gif, gganimate

I am trying to generate a plot that represents the induction of specific markers over time. I have managed to generate a great core for singe markers. However, when creating the animation for all markers into one plot I get the error

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "group", value = "") :
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
# Set the working directory to the location of your file
setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path))

# Read the data from the Excel file
df <- read_xlsx("All_Parameters_Single_Markers.xlsx")

# Subset based on reactors
subset_df <- df %>%
  dplyr::filter(str_detect(Sample, 'R20|R21|R50|R52')) %>% 
  drop_na(Sample)

# Extract stage and day from the 'Sample' column
subset_df <- subset_df %>%
  mutate(Stage = str_extract(Sample, 'S\\d'),
         Day = str_extract(Sample, 'D\\d'),
         Reactor_Volume = if_else(str_detect(Sample, 'R20|R21'), '3L', '15L'),
         Stage_Day = paste(Stage, Day, sep="_")) %>% 
  relocate(Reactor_Volume, Stage, Day, .after = Sample)

# Pivot the subset_df to longer format to plot individual replicates for each marker
long_subset_df <- subset_df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(Sample, Stage, Day, Reactor_Volume, Stage_Day),
               names_to = "Marker",
               values_to = "Value")

# Convert Stage_Day to a numeric sequence for long_subset_df
long_subset_df$Numeric_Day <- as.numeric(factor(long_subset_df$Stage_Day, levels = unique(long_subset_df$Stage_Day)))

# Loess prediction function for the given reactor volume
get_loess_prediction <- function(data, reactor_volume) {
  loess_fit <- loess(Value ~ Numeric_Day, data=dplyr::filter(data, Reactor_Volume == reactor_volume), span = 0.2)
  pred <- predict(loess_fit, newdata=data.frame(Numeric_Day=unique(data$Numeric_Day)))
  predictions <- data.frame(Numeric_Day=unique(data$Numeric_Day), Value=pred, Reactor_Volume=reactor_volume)
  return(predictions)
}

# Get predictions for both 3L and 15L reactors
predictions_3L_all <- get_loess_prediction(long_subset_df, "3L")
predictions_3L_all$Marker <- long_subset_df$Marker[match(predictions_3L_all$Numeric_Day, long_subset_df$Numeric_Day)]

predictions_15L_all <- get_loess_prediction(long_subset_df, "15L")
predictions_15L_all$Marker <- long_subset_df$Marker[match(predictions_15L_all$Numeric_Day, long_subset_df$Numeric_Day)]

# Combine all predictions
combined_predictions_all <- rbind(predictions_3L_all, predictions_15L_all)

colors <- c("#1f77b4", "#ff7f0e", "#2ca02c", "#d62728", "#9467bd", "#8c564b", "#e377c2", "#7f7f7f", "#bcbd22", "#17becf", "#a02c70")

lookup_table <- unique(data.frame(Numeric_Day = long_subset_df$Numeric_Day, 
                                  Stage_Day = long_subset_df$Stage_Day))

create_animation_for_all_markers <- function(data, colors){
  
  # Empty dataframe to store combined predictions
  combined_predictions_all <- data.frame()
  
  # Iterate over each marker to generate predictions
  for(marker_name in unique(data$Marker)){
    
    anim_data <- data %>% dplyr::filter(Marker == marker_name)
    anim_data$Numeric_Day <- as.numeric(factor(anim_data$Stage_Day, levels = unique(anim_data$Stage_Day)))
    
    # Loess prediction for 3L
    loess_3L <- loess(Value ~ Numeric_Day, data=dplyr::filter(anim_data, Reactor_Volume == "3L"), span = 0.4)
    pred_3L <- predict(loess_3L, newdata=data.frame(Numeric_Day=unique(anim_data$Numeric_Day)), span = 0.4)
    predictions_3L <- data.frame(Numeric_Day=unique(anim_data$Numeric_Day), Value=pred_3L, Reactor_Volume="3L", Marker=marker_name)
    
    # Loess prediction for 15L
    loess_15L <- loess(Value ~ Numeric_Day, data=dplyr::filter(anim_data, Reactor_Volume == "15L"), span = 0.18)
    pred_15L <- predict(loess_15L, newdata=data.frame(Numeric_Day=unique(anim_data$Numeric_Day)), span = 0.18)
    predictions_15L <- data.frame(Numeric_Day=unique(anim_data$Numeric_Day), Value=pred_15L, Reactor_Volume="15L", Marker=marker_name)
    
    # Combine and append to the master dataframe
    combined_predictions_all <- rbind(combined_predictions_all, predictions_3L, predictions_15L)
  }
  
  # Split the data into a list of data frames by Numeric_Day
  data_list <- split(data, data$Numeric_Day)
  
  # Tween the data to create intermediate frames
  tweened_data <- tweenr::tween_states(data_list, tweenlength = 1, statelength = 1, ease = 'linear', nframes = 100)
  
  # Plotting
  anim_plot <- ggplot() +
    geom_point(data=data, aes(x=Numeric_Day, y=Value, color=Marker, group=interaction(Marker, Sample)), shape=1, size=3, alpha=0.5) +
    geom_line(data=combined_predictions_all, aes(x=Numeric_Day, y=Value, color=Marker, linetype=Reactor_Volume, group=paste(Marker, Reactor_Volume)), linewidth=1.5) +
    labs(title="Expression of all markers over time: {current_frame}",
         y="Marker Value",
         x="Stage and Day") +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=unique(long_subset_df$Numeric_Day), labels=unique(long_subset_df$Stage_Day)) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100), breaks = seq(0, 100, 10)) +
    scale_color_manual(values=colors) +
    scale_linetype_manual(values=c("3L"="dashed", "15L"="solid")) +
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1)) +
    transition_reveal2(along = Numeric_Day) +
    shadow_mark() +
    enter_fade() + 
    exit_fade() +
    theme_avenir(base_size = 16, axis_title_just = "mc") +  # Setting base font size
    theme(
      plot.title = element_text(size = 32, face = "bold"),
      axis.title.x = element_text(size = 32, face = "bold", vjust = 0.5),
      axis.title.y = element_text(size = 32,  face = "bold", hjust = 0.5),
      axis.text.x = element_text(size = 28, angle = 90, hjust = 1),
      axis.text.y = element_text(size = 28),
      legend.text = element_text(size = 26),
      legend.position = "none"
    )
  # Save the animation
  anim_save("all_markers_animation.gif", animate(anim_plot, height = 1080, width = 1920, fps = 10, rewind = FALSE, renderer = gifski_renderer(loop = F)))
}

create_animation_for_all_markers(long_subset_df, colors)
```

This code generates a good animation, however it is pre-calculating the smoothing of the lines and using geom_line instead of geom_smooth. The output looks like this:

[image]

However, I want the data to look smoother like this plot:

[image]

I have tried using the following code within the "create_animation_for_all_markers":

```
create_animation_for_all_markers <- function(data, colors) {
  
  # Animation plot
  anim_plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Numeric_Day, y = Value, color = Marker)) +
    geom_point(aes(group = interaction(Marker, Sample)), shape = 1, size = 3, alpha = 0.5) +
    labs(title = "Expression of all markers over time: {closest_state}",
         y = "Marker Value",
         x = "Stage and Day") +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique(data$Numeric_Day), labels = unique(data$Stage_Day)) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100), breaks = seq(0, 100, 10)) +
    scale_color_manual(values = colors) +
    scale_linetype_manual(values = c("3L" = "dashed", "15L" = "solid")) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
    transition_reveal(Numeric_Day) +
    shadow_mark() +
    enter_fade() + 
    exit_fade() +
    theme_avenir(base_size = 16, axis_title_just = "mc") +  # Setting base font size
    theme(
      plot.title = element_text(size = 32, face = "bold"),
      axis.title.x = element_text(size = 32, face = "bold", vjust = 0.5),
      axis.title.y = element_text(size = 32, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5),
      axis.text.x = element_text(size = 28, angle = 90, hjust = 1),
      axis.text.y = element_text(size = 28),
      legend.text = element_text(size = 26),
      legend.position = "none"
    )
  
  anim_plot = anim_plot +
    geom_smooth(aes(group = interaction(Marker, Reactor_Volume), linetype = Reactor_Volume), method = "loess", se = FALSE)
    
  # Save the animation
  anim_save("all_markers_animation_smooth.gif", animate(anim_plot, height = 1080, width = 1920, fps = 10, rewind = FALSE, renderer = gifski_renderer(loop = F)))
}
```

However, I get the error:

```
ror in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "group", value = "") :
replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

Hopefully someone know a trick to overcome the issue with animating multiple geom_smooth.

Thanks!